# Improve CSS debugging experience in WebPack

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have recently moved to WebPack (v3) from a Gulp based build system, and for the most part its pretty good. I am however struggling to get the CSS development experience to match what I previously had.

I write my CSS using SASS and then use the following setup in WebPack

**Module.Rules:**

```
{
    test: /\.(s*)css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { minimize: isProd }
            },
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
        ],
    })
},
```

**Plugins:**

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'app.bundle.css',
    disable: !isProd
}),
```

So when I am in develpoment i.e. `!isProd` the `ExtractTestPlugin` is disabled and it uses the fallback of `style-loader`.  This allows Hot CSS replacement. Without this the entire page would have to be refreshed to show CSS updates.

This all works great, I change CSS and a split second later its shown on screen, however, trying to debug what file or rule a CSS selector is in is proving problematic.

[image]

In this case I want to see what style is causing the `font-size` to be `1.5rem`. I dont believe it to be in my CSS (I think its a third party library) but its nigh on impossible for me to find out the cause  (I have ~50 inline styles added) and clicking the style tag link (which would previously take me to the CSS file with correct line number) now just takes me to the start of the `<style>` tag.

How can I improve this experience? I'd be happy with a single `app.bundle.css` file that is linked normally (not inline - so I get line numbers) but I really want to keep HMR for CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by adding source maps it effectively masks the delivery method (style tags) and gives the browser direct links to the source code which works correctly.

See this [github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/30#issuecomment-131956403) post for some information.

Here is my final CSS WebPack code

```
{
    test: /\.(s*)css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { minimize: isProd, sourceMap: true }
            },
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: { sourceMap: true }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { sourceMap: true }
            }
        ],
    })
},
```